# removing the last line of files using PowerShell command

Tags: powershell

I would like to remove last line of few files using PowerShell command. I saw the following which does the same thing for the first line of the files. How can I modify that to remove the last line of the files?

```
gci *.txt | % { (gc $_) | ? { (1) -notcontains $_.ReadCount } | sc -path $_ }
```

I will appreciate it if I also get the explanation for the commands.

Cheers,
Siavoush

I haven't try anything yet.

Answer (score 0):

Undoubtedly there are a number of solutions for this.
The below one should perform quite fast:

```
# create a List object to store the contents of the files
$list = [System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]::new()
Get-ChildItem -Path 'X:\Where\The\Files\Are' -Filter '*.txt' -File | ForEach-Object {
    $list.AddRange([System.IO.File]::ReadAllLines($_.FullName))
    $list.RemoveAt($list.Count - 1)
    [System.IO.File]::WriteAllLines($_.FullName, $list)
    $list.Clear()
}
```

---

Some explanation to the code above:

- Because an array is **static**, adding or removing elements from it is a time and memory consuming thing to do because the entire array would need to be recreated in memory.
  This is why I chose to wrk with the [System.Collections.Generic.List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1) object that is optimized for adding or removing elements.
- Instead of using `Get-Content`, I chose to use .Net `[System.IO.File]::ReadAllLines()` method because that has less overhead and performs faster when reading an entire text file as array of lines
- `$list.RemoveAt($list.Count - 1)` takes away the last element (line) from the array of lines
- `[System.IO.File]::WriteAllLines($_.FullName, $list)` rewrites the lines (minus the last because we removed that) back to the file, overwriting the original content
- finally, `$list.Clear()` empties the List object to get it ready for the next file

Comment: Hi Theo, Would you please let me know how to use these commands. And, would you please also explain what each line does. Thanks.

Comment: @user634433 Please see my edit where I have added explanation for the code. In the meantime, may I invite you to read the [tour] where amongst other interesting things about SO, you can see how to mark a question 'done' when an answer solves your problem.